# How do i change a value inside the model from view when user presses button?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Im working on a web-based project that deals a lot of data that it always take a lot of time loading. What i plan on doing is to incrementally load the data as the user presses button.

model.php

```
$items_per_page = 20;
$position = 0;
$this->db->limit($items_per_page,$position);
```

view.php (pseudocode)

```
<button onClick="//change $position=20 and items_per_page=40">Load MORE</button>
```

What i want is that to change the position and the items_per_page displayed as the user clicks a button say Load MORE. Or is there any other better way on doing this? Im using mysql on codeigniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter has a library dedicated to exactly what you want to achieve - the term you are looking for is called "pagination".

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html

The CI user guide is very helpful, I'd read up on the pagination library.

If you really wanted to use jQuery, you'd have read up on using AJAX to display the information to the browser.

Comment: i would like to implement twitter like pagination :D is that AJAX?

Comment: Yes that would require AJAX.